# The existence of compact Kähler manifolds satisfying $h^{1,1}=h^{2,2}$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Recently I have been thinking about a problem. During this process I faced a phenomenon which is related to those Kähler manifolds whose Hodge numbers satisfy $h^{1,1}=h^{2,2}$. Except $\mathbf{CP}^n$, are there any compact Kähler manifolds whose Hodge numbers satisfy $h^{1,1}=h^{2,2}$? At this moment, I don't have any such examples. I have calculated $A_n$-type flag manifolds and some hyper-Kähler manifolds, but none of them satisfy this condition.

Do some experts know any such an example other than $\mathbf{CP}^n$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry. I suddenly realize that my favoriate manifolds $CP^n\sharp\bar{CP^n}$ ($n\geq 2$) satisfy this condition:-)
Are there any more such examples? 

Comment: Any smooth hypersurface of any degree in $\mathbb P^n$ for $n \geq 6$ has this property by the Lefschetz theorem.

Comment: Cheap example: any threefold.

Comment: Also, fake projective planes:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fake_projective_plane